# How to change from an object on canvas RectTransform coordinates to screen coordinates?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas

I have this code working on Update:

```
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            touchPosition = touch.position;

            if(arRaycastManager.Raycast(touchPosition, hits, UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.TrackableType.PlaneWithinPolygon))
            {
                Pose hitPose = hits[0].pose;//ok
            }
        }
     }
```

But now I have to use a joystick to make a pointer move on the screen, then push a button to do something.

Like this:

```
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    fakeFinger.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition += new 
    Vector2(h * vel * Time.deltaTime, v * vel * Time.deltaTime);
    //this move a pointer on my screen... I had to use RectTransform... dont know if its right

    if (considerjoystickbuttonpressedok)
    {
        touchPosition = new Vector2(fakeFinger.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition.x,
                                    fakeFinger.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition.y);
         //still dont know if its right above...

        if (arRaycastManager.Raycast(touchPosition, hits, UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.TrackableType.PlaneWithinPolygon))
        {
            Pose hitPose = hits[0].pose;//NOT OK!
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public Vector3 GetScreenPosition()
{
    RectTransform rectTransform = (RectTransform)transform;
    Vector4 worldLocation = transform.localToWorldMatrix * new Vector4(rectTransform.anchoredPosition3D.x,
                                                   rectTransform.anchoredPosition3D.y,
                                                   rectTransform.anchoredPosition3D.z,
                                                   1);

    return yourCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(new Vector3(worldLocation.x, worldLocation.y, worldLocation.z));
}
```

Comment: Hi Sir @Brian, thank you for your answer. It helped me get in the direction, but not quite accomplish yet. 

Please look at this image: https://ibb.co/VLTGnzF

There we have a "touch start" and a "touch end" position, clicking on the screen, I measure my Mac there, "distance by finger", its ok. 

I use the joystick to put that pointer (finger) on that same positions in the world, measurement my Mac.

On the left, so we have "joy start" and "joy end" positions... and a "distance by joy". Quite different... but the best result so far...

I will use another comment to put the code:

Comment: Oh my, couldnt post the code as comment, made a answer to my own question... I think stackoverflow community will kill me...

Comment: Anyway, I changed GetScreenPosition() method to the best I could get, this is the version that made that screenshot above. I think I am misunderting which transform to use

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;

    public class SomeClassOnMyARSessionOriginThatContainsMyARCamera : MonoBehaviour
    {     
     public ARCameraManager arCameraManager;//its another child go
     public ARRaycastManager arRaycastManager;
     private static List<ARRaycastHit> hits = new List<ARRaycastHit>();
     private Vector2 touchPosition = default;

     public GameObject startPoint;
     public GameObject endPoint;
     public GameObject startPointbyJoy;
     public GameObject endPointbyJoy;

     public GameObject finger;//It´s a UICanvas
     public float vel;

     void Update()
     {        
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        finger.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition += new Vector2(h * vel * Time.deltaTime, v * vel * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.JoystickButton13))
        {
            Vector3 fingerScreenPos = GetScreenPosition(finger);
            touchPosition = new Vector2(fingerScreenPos.x, fingerScreenPos.y);//here I use that method

            if (arRaycastManager.Raycast(touchPosition, hits, UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.TrackableType.PlaneWithinPolygon))
            {
                startPointbyJoy.SetActive(true);
                Pose hitPose = hits[0].pose;
                startPointbyJoy.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(hitPose.position, hitPose.rotation);
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.JoystickButton12))
        {            
            Vector3 fingerScreenPos = GetScreenPosition(finger);
            touchPosition = new Vector2(fingerScreenPos.x, fingerScreenPos.y);//here I use that method

            if (arRaycastManager.Raycast(touchPosition, hits, UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.TrackableType.PlaneWithinPolygon))
            {
                endPointbyJoy.SetActive(true);
                Pose hitPose = hits[0].pose;
                endPointbyJoy.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(hitPose.position, hitPose.rotation);
            }
        }

        if (Input.touchCount > 0)//these are OK
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                touchPosition = touch.position;
                if (arRaycastManager.Raycast(touchPosition, hits, UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.TrackableType.PlaneWithinPolygon))
                {
                    startPoint.SetActive(true);
                    Pose hitPose = hits[0].pose;
                    startPoint.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(hitPose.position, hitPose.rotation);

                }
            }
            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                touchPosition = touch.position;                
                if(arRaycastManager.Raycast(touchPosition, hits, UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.TrackableType.PlaneWithinPolygon))
                {                    
                    endPoint.SetActive(true);
                    Pose hitPose = hits[0].pose;
                    endPoint.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(hitPose.position, hitPose.rotation);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Vector3 GetScreenPosition(GameObject finger)
    {
    //HERE. Which "transform" should I get? The UICancas finger?
    //The go this script is attached to?
        RectTransform rectTransform = (RectTransform)finger.transform;
        Vector4 worldLocation = rectTransform.localToWorldMatrix * new  Vector4(rectTransform.anchoredPosition3D.x,
                                                        rectTransform.anchoredPosition3D.y,
                                                        rectTransform.anchoredPosition3D.z,
                                                       1);

        //is it different using a arcamera?
        return arCameraManager.GetComponent<Camera>().WorldToScreenPoint(new Vector3(worldLocation.x, worldLocation.y, worldLocation.z));
     }
    }
```

Comment: yeah, this is correct if I do, I will do the same thing as you did here.
I would use code like change script as "RectTransform rectTransform = finger.transform" but doesn't matter.